# Div contents not visible in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a site here: [bgflirt.com](http://bgflirt.com)

On the right side of the pictures in the middle is a div tag that shows nothing in everything but firefox. There is a flash object over there and a "test" string. Any ideas why it doesn't show in IE and Chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, try to load flash object with [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). It makes it easier to embed flash animation into your page and takes care about browsers problem.

Second thing, you got this in your code just before your swf insertion :

```
<div class="entry">
                                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>

 <w:WordDocument>

  <w:View>Normal</w:View>

  <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>

  <w:TrackMoves/>

  <w:TrackFormatting/>

  <w:HyphenationZone>21</w:HyphenationZone>

  <w:PunctuationKerning/>

  <w:Valida&hellip; <a href="http://bgflirt.com/news/view/2/">Още..</a>
                            </div>
```

You use a `strict` doctype. It can lead to problem depending on browser.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the problem is in the doctype I use. What doctype should I use so it DOES work correctly ?

Comment: Huhuh, no, the problem may come from the copy/paste you made from word which is useless **and** incompatible with a strict doctype.

Comment: so the entire  <!--[if gte mso 9]> part should be deleted ?

Comment: oh, I understand.. our editior copied the news from word.. :D thanks man